# Get all the tokens which are included in a String

Tags: java, algorithm, substring, token, tokenize

I require your help, i am receiving a URL and it will include tokens which i need to compute for other thing. So basically i need to extract all the tokens in a list or another string.

i.e
String url= "https://example.com/#EMAIL#/F77A1B8BDF89B7E4E90206DAC26AA737?firstname=#FIRSTNAME#&lastname=#LASTNAME#"

so the result should be:
result: #EMAIL#, #FIRSTNAME# , #LASTNAME#

I have tried:
StringUtils.substringBetween(url,"#");
StringTokenizer tokenizer= new StringTokenizer(url,"#");

but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: I think email can contain # characters, that complicates things?

Comment: [Parsing a URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html).  After you've separated the URL into parts, you can use the regular expressions in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to extract all characters between `#` characters.

```java
var tokens = Pattern.compile("#[^#]+#").matcher(url).results()
                    .map(MatchResult::group).toList();
```

You could also use Apache Common Lang's [`StringUtils.substringsBetween`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), but it will remove the delimiting characters in the result.

```java
String[] tokens = StringUtils.substringsBetween(url, "#", "#");
```